# Environment variables, PHP & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, api, environment-variables, payment

I am new to programming and now I am trying to implement a payment api (Paylike). Besides being really confused from its documentation, I was wondering how I can use a .env file such that I have access to environment variables both from JavaScript and from PHP?

On another perspective, can you please explain me how would using a .env file workout? I am using Heroku for free hosting and in .gitignore I've put the .env file. How is the app supposed to know the values if when I am pushing the committed changes to the repository the .env file is not pushed?

Thank you very much for your help, time, and attention!

Comment: You can use dotenv package.
https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

Answer (score 0):

You can use any env parser.

For js, you can use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv
For PHP as @B.C.h suggested https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

About .gitignore and .env
Environment variables are used to save sensitive information like auth, tokens, passwords, etc.
So best practice is not to automatically deploy it.
Copy values from .env and create it in the Heroku app, or add it manually https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: Thank you very much! This will definitely be helpful!